# Why is $\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a+1}{b+1}=\frac{a-b}{b(b+1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I typed $\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a+1}{b+1}$ into wolfram alpha an got $\frac{a-b}{b(b+1)}$ How can I get this myself?

Comment: Put the fractions over the common denominator $\,b(b+1)\,$ then subtract.

Comment: Oh yes, yes of course. Thanks

Comment: Would you like to type that as an answer?

Comment: Ok, done, and I explained why it works.

Comment: Because common denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Put both fractions over a common denominator, then subtract.

The reason that works is as follows

$\begin{eqnarray} && \ \ \ x&=& a/b&,&\ \ \ \ \ y &=& c/d\\
 \iff&&\ bx &=& a&,&\ \ \ dy &=& c \\ 
\iff&& bdx &=& ad&,&\ bdy &=& bc \end{eqnarray}$

$\quad\ \begin{eqnarray}
\Rightarrow&& bd(x + y) &=&\ \ \, ad+bc\quad\ \ \text{ by adding above}\\
\Rightarrow && \quad\ x+y &=&\, (ad+ bc)/bd\,  =\, ad/bd + bc/bd\end{eqnarray}$

Such fraction arithmetic rules are *universal*. They will work in any system of numbers (i.e. [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29)) where the denominators $\,b,d\,$ are invertible. [For example,](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com+%28gone+OR+Dubuque+OR+gems+OR+%22key+ideas%22%29+beware+fraction) in integer arithmetic mod $\,m,\,$ where the denominators are coprime to $\,m,\,$ hence invertible (by Bezout).